# Editing Vertices, Edges, & Faces in Edit Mode

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode, properties, panel

I have a [FloatProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#getter-setter-example) that I'm displaying in a Panel in the `VIEW_3D`. With its `get` and `set` methods, I'm trying to adjust the selected edges' lengths (code, below). The issue is that the mesh's information doesn't update without switching to `OBJECT` mode. That's not possible when the property is being drawn in a `VIEW_3D` Panel in `EDIT` mode. How can I approach this to where I can edit the mesh's vertices, edges, and faces with the API in real time?

```py
def get_selected_edges_length(self):
    if bpy.context.object is None or bpy.context.object.type != 'MESH':
        return 0.0

    obj = bpy.context.object
    mesh = obj.data

    if bpy.context.mode != 'EDIT_MESH':
        return 0.0

    selected_edges = [e for e in mesh.edges if e.select]
    total_length = 0.0

    if len(selected_edges) > 0:
        for edge in selected_edges:
            verts = [obj.matrix_world @ mesh.vertices[vert_id].co for vert_id in edge.vertices]
            total_length += (verts[1] - verts[0]).length

    return total_length

def set_selected_edges_length(self, length):
    if bpy.context.object is None or bpy.context.object.type != 'MESH':
        return

    obj = bpy.context.object
    mesh = obj.data

    if bpy.context.mode != 'EDIT_MESH':
        return

    if length <= 0.0:
        return

    if bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode[1]:
        active_vertex = obj.matrix_world @ mesh.vertices[mesh.edges[obj.data.edges.active.index].vertices[1]].co
    else:
        active_vertex = obj.matrix_world @ mesh.vertices[mesh.edges[obj.data.edges.active.index].vertices[0]].co

    selected_edges = [e for e in mesh.edges if e.select]

    if len(selected_edges) > 0:
        for edge in selected_edges:
            verts = [obj.matrix_world @ mesh.vertices[vert_id].co for vert_idin edge.vertices]
            original_length = (verts[1] - verts[0]).length
            current_length = length
            scale_factor = current_length / original_length

            if bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode[1]:
                mid_point = (verts[0] + active_vertex) * 0.5
                verts[0] = mid_point + (verts[0] - mid_point) * scale_factor
                verts[1] = mid_point + (verts[1] - mid_point) * scale_factor
            else:
                verts[0] = active_vertex + (verts[0] - active_vertex) * scale_factor
                verts[1] = active_vertex + (verts[1] - active_vertex) * scale_factor

            for i, vert_idin enumerate(edge.vertices):
                mesh.vertices[vert_id].co = obj.matrix_world.inverted() @ verts[i]
```